# Does this method in runnable object needs synchronization?

Tags: java, thread-safety, synchronized

The following method belongs to an object A that implements Runnable. It's called asynchronously by other method from the object A and by code inside the run method (so, it's called from other thread, with a period of 5 seconds).

Could I end up with file creation exceptions?

If i make the method synchronized... the lock is always acquired over the object A ?
The fact that one of the callers is at the *run()* method confuses me :S

Thanks for your inputs.

```
private void saveMap(ConcurrentMap<String, String> map) {
    ObjectOutputStream obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("map.txt"));
        obj.writeObject(map);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MessagesFileManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            obj.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MessagesFileManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    notifyActionListeners();
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you're saying that this method is invoked from two different threads or if it's just a single thread running it every 5 seconds. If there's only one thread running it, there's no need or use in synchronizing the method.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Yes it's invoked from two different threads. One is the one that directly uses Object A and the other is a Thread object created like this: `Thread t = new Thread(object A);`

Comment: It looks quite odd to use the class directly and then use it as a Runnable.  We can't see what you are doing, but maybe you should rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks toto2, your answer made me think. The main responsability of the class is to collect data from an input file, which is done inside the run() method. The other methods are for querying data collected inside run() and saved at the ConcurrentHashMap, and to make the cached data persistent (saveMap), each time an object is added or removed.

Answer (score 6):

Synchronized instance methods use the `this` object as the lock and prevent simultaneous execution of *all* synchronized instance methods (even other ones) from different threads.

To answer your question regarding requirements for synchronization, the answer is basically *yes* because you have multiple threads accessing the same method, so output may collide.

As a design comment, I would make your `saveMap` method `static`, because it doesn't access any fields (it's stateless), and it more strongly indicates that output to the file is *not* dependent on the instance, so it's more obvious that file output may collide with other instances.

#### Edited:

Here's the code for what I'm suggesting:

```
private static synchronized void saveMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    ...
}
```

FYI, `static synchronized` methods use the class object (ie MyClass.class), which is a singleton, as the lock object.

Comment: So it would be better to have a `private static Object mapWriteLock = new Object()` as a member of class A and then `private static void saveMap(...) {synchronize(mapWriteLock) {... same as before ...}}`.

Comment: @toto2 No - just make the method `static synchronized`. See edit

Comment: Thanks you very much Bohemian. It's a really nice tip the one about the static keyword. 
If a method is stateless, should it always be static? I can think of an improvement in memory efficiency ( instances will have less code ) Am I right? Are there other benefits?
By the way, the first time i wrote that code i was sure that using a ConcurrentHashMap made the whole thing thread-safe, but now i'm pretty sure that i was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Although not required, stateless methods should be static as a clear signal to readers and users of the code that the method is stateless. It also automatically raises a red flag if stateful code is introduced  - you'll get a compiler error trying to access instance fields from a static method. At that point you can either make the fields static or make the method non-static. Whatever the choice, at least it'll be forced to be made consciously (and therefore correctly)

Comment: Just to clarify my comment: I was referring to your "prevent simultaneous execution of _all_ synchronized instance methods (even other ones)".  So it would be overkill to synchronize on `this` since it could slow everything down, even unrelated synchronized methods that also lock on `this`.  There might be other methods that access `map.txt` and only those should use the same lock as `saveMap`.

Comment: Actually, synchronization doesn't slow things down much at all, except that it serializes execution; the actual locking mechanism is now quite lightweight. Synchronized instance methods are equivalent to `synchronized (this) { ... }`. And, if you need synchronization you need it. Don't worry about performance until it becomes a problem: It's easier to speed up a correctly behaving program than it is to fix a fast but buggy program, *especially* debugging a multi-threaded program! The *use* of a `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't imbue a program with thread-safety - only its *methods* are thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

> It's called asynchronously by other method from the object `A` and by code inside the `run` method (so, it's called from other thread, with a period of 5 seconds).

Given that `saveMap` is called from multiple threads, without synchronization you cannot guarantee that two threads won't try to write to the same file concurrently. This will cause an incorrectly-formatted file when it happens.

The simplest solution is to make the method synchronized.

```
private synchronized void saveMap(ConcurrentMap<String, String> map) { ... }
```

If the map is large enough, this may cause unresponsiveness in your program. Another option is to write to a temporary file (a new file each time it's called) and then use synchronization while swapping the new file over `map.txt` by renaming and deleting.

```
private void saveMap(ConcurrentMap<String, String> map) {
    File file = ... original code to write to a temporary file ...
    if (file != null) {
        synchronized(this) {
            ... move file over map.txt ...
        }
        notifyActionListeners();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that swapping two files won't be an atomic operation. Any external program or thread from the same program may catch the short time that `map.txt` doesn't exist. I was unable to find an atomic file-swap method in Java, but maybe with some searching you will.